# How to send specific fields from EventBridge input to its target

Tags: amazon-web-services, jsonpath, aws-event-bridge

I am receiving a webhook event on my AWS EventBridge. The event json body is pretty large and I need to transfer only 4 fields to the target. The fields are :

{"browser_ip":"$.detail.payload.browser_ip","created_at":"$.detail.payload.created_at","email":"$.detail.payload.email","shopify_order_id":"$.detail.payload.id"}

I have tried the "**Configure Input**" --> "**Part of the matched eventInfo**" option, but it works only when I add just 1 parameter lets say the "$.detail.payload". When I add multiple parameters , it says the input path is invalid. I could not find any example on how to add multiple parts of the matched event info. Is it possible ? If yes then what am I doing wrong?

[image]
[image]
Regards,
Lina

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer. Instead of using the "part of the event matched" , I used the input transformer as the following :

[image]

Worked properly . I have the json format in the target.

Comment: I had put pretty-JSON (exactly as per "Example input paths, Templates and Outputs" and I ran into this error, putting the exact same JSON in one line made this error go away